# How to run custom action based on condition?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, custom-action

I'm trying to run a custom action (delete a certain file) based on the windows version.
I know how to check for the windows version:

```
<Condition Message="Windows version xxx required...">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 600)]]>
</Condition>
```

However, I do not want to display a message, but delete a file. I can't find an example on how to use such a condition to run oder not to run a custom action!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify the condition inside the [Custom element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/custom.html) which runs your custom action. (This allows you to run the custom action multiple times in different locations in your sequence and with different conditions each time if desired).

Example:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CreateRegistryEntries" After="CostInitialize">
    NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Thx! But how can I check the windows version like this?
Custom Action="CreateRegistryEntries" After="CostInitialize">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT >= 600]]>
  </Custom>

?

Comment: I think you can just do it without the CDATA tags